NSPopUpButton Size Issue: Width is larger than what imposed by constraints
I have a problem with a subclassed NSPopUpButton in OSX.  Subclassing is nothing special, just draws the string and image based on the font chosen.
The problem is that when I add the NSButton to a view and, using layout constraints, set its width to a fixed CGFloat value, the button is always larger than the constraint and its leading anchor is also in the wrong place (i.e. to the left of the leading anchor I set originally).
For example, if I add a button to a view in a window (say a rectangular container) and pin its leading anchor to the container leading anchor and give it a width of 80px, the button then appears with its left side 3px to the left of the container leading anchor and its width is 87px, not 80.
The 3 and 7 px difference is always the same, regardless of which width I give the button.
I have also checked in draw(rect) and the received rect is actually 7px wider than the constant I imposed with the constraints.
Can someone help, there must be some sort of embedded OSX process that changes the width of the NSControl).
As I use the same subclass (with the necessary minor modifications) in iOS as well, the problem does not appear and the button is correctly sized.

Try overriding alignmentRectInsets to return NSEdgeInsetsZero.

Thas what I needed. Thanks @Sweeper

Printing NSPopUpButton().alignmentRectInsets produces
NSEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 3.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 4.0)

This is why the layout anchors are all a bit off. They have been moved by some non-zero amount.
If you don't want that, override alignmentRectInsets to return 0:
override var alignmentRectInsets: NSEdgeInsets {
    NSEdgeInsetsZero
}

